# move html code to a seperate html document in Angular CLI

Tags: html, angular

How do I move my html section from `app.compontent.ts` to a seperate html documenet? It wont work to just att the html code into the generated class `app.component.ts`.

Also I would like to move the css section as well to seperate css document.
If someone could help me or point me to the right direction I would be greatfull

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';




@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: ` 
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
            <button> my Button </button>
        <h2 pButton type="button" icon="fa-check" iconPos="right">My Heroes</h2>
        <ul class="heroes">
            <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" 
                [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
                (click)="onSelect(hero)">
                <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span>{{hero.name}} 
            </li>
        </ul>

        <hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></hero-detail>

    `,
    styles: [`
      .selected {
        background-color: #CFD8DC !important;
        color: white;
      }
      .heroes {
        margin: 0 0 2em 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        width: 15em;
      }
      .heroes li {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #EEE;
        margin: .5em;
        padding: .3em 0;
        height: 1.6em;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }
    `],
    providers: [HeroService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    heroes: Hero[];
    selectedHero: Hero;

    constructor(private heroService: HeroService){
    }

    getHeroes(): void{
        this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
    }
    onSelect(hero: Hero): void{
        this.selectedHero = hero;
    }
    ngOnInit(): void{
        this.getHeroes();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `templateUrl` instead of `template` in Component Decorator

> templateUrl - url to an external file containing a template for the
>   view

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

Add all the code to `app.component.html`

Answer (score 0):

create separate html and css example :  **home.component.html** and **home.component.css**

in component.ts file add below code

```
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
```

Comment: what is the difference from my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add the html code in a separate html file for example: `app.component.html`
Copy the template without the  inside the app.component.html .
Later in your @Component make the below changes:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
```

Comment: what is the difference from my answer

Comment: @RahulSingh There was no answer when we posted it :)

Comment: the timestamp says it all

Comment: @RahulSingh It didn't say when i wrote the answer .